# Make context menu ignore right-click when user is selecting a context menu item

Tags: c#, contextmenu, right-click

I defined a ContextMenuStrip context menu in the Visual Studio C# IDE and coded the program so that the context menu successfully pops up when the user right-clicks an object on the screen. The user can choose an item from the context menu and the code successfully determines which context menu item was selected by the user. So far so good. The problem is that the context menu accepts a right-click as a mechanism for choosing a context menu item. 
I noticed this when I accidentally double-right-clicked an object on the screen ... The menu popped up with the first click and the immediate second click ended up choosing the context menu item that happened to be painted under the mouse cursor.

My searches have only resulted in ways to make a context menu pop up in response to a right-click, but not how to deal with (or ignore) right-click while the menu is being displayed.

Here's the command that displays the context menu:

```
ctxMenu.Show(this, pt);
```

where "this" is the form and "pt" is the point on the form where the mouse was clicked.

And here's a snippet of code that fires when a context menu item is chosen:

```
private void ctxMenu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
  // Make context menu go away
  ctxMenu.Hide();
  switch (e.ClickedItem.Text)
  {
    case "blah blah blah"
    ...
    break;
  }
}
```

Context menus in Microsoft Office products like Word and Excel ignore right-clicks, even for displaying sub-menus. Is there a way to make the C# ContextMenuStrip ignore right-clicks, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a rather involved 5-step solution. If any of you have a more direct approach, please share it.

1. Add a bool property to the form class, such as:

   `private bool retryContextMenu = false;`
2. Add a MouseClick event handler to the form, such as:

   `private void ctxMenu_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
     if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) retryContextMenu = true;
     else retryContextMenu = false;
   }`

Note that the MouseClick event fires before the ItemClicked event does, and MouseClick lets you identify which mouse button was pressed.

3. Set the ContextMenuStrip's AutoClose property to FALSE. When it was set to the default value of true, I could not prevent the menu from closing itself. Even adding a conditional call to 
   `ctxMenu.Show()`
   in the Closed event did not keep the menu visible.
4. Add a method to close the context menu and reset the flag, such as:

   `private void CancelPopup()
   {
     if (ctxMenu.Visible) ctxMenu.Close();
     retryContextMenu = false; 
   }`

In my case, I added calls to CancelPopup() in all the methods that are triggered by user mouse clicks of any kind.

5. Modify the previously shown ItemClicked event handler to:

   `private void ctxMenu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
   {
     if (retryContextMenu) return; // If not a valid user click, don't process
     CancelPopup(); // Make context menu go away
     switch (e.ClickedItem.Text)
     {
       case "blah blah blah":
         ...
         break;
       ...
     }
   }`